# Should tachanun be said in a mourner's shtiebl?

Tags: synagogue, mourning-aveilus, tachanun

Many *shtiebls* are set up as shuls that are part of someone's home.

This raises the question as to what is considered a "mourner's home" with regard to saying *tachanun*.

**Background:** Tachanun is not recited if people are praying in a mourner's home. However, if a mourner attends a synagogue outside his home, tachanun is recited. In short, the cancellation of tachanun is dependent on the place, itself (mourner's home), not the person (the mourner being present.)

So, my question is, if the shul is part of the mourner's home and people pray there, while the mourner is there, as well, does it have the status of a shul, as any other, or the status of a mourner's home?

Does it matter if the mourner dedicates that room specifically as a shul only or if it is a "multi-purpose" room? I.e., it is used as a shul for daily minyanim; it has an Aron Kodesh, ner tamid, etc. but during the year, the residents also eat their meals in the shul.

Comment: Is the mourner praying in _his_ shtiebl? I think that would be one of the only parameters to consider.

Comment: @DannySchoemann That's precise. I assumed that would be obvious in my question, but I guess it isn't. I'll add it.

Comment: In practice, I recall _tachanun_ not having been recited when the Rov of the shul was sitting _shiva_ in the shul, which is the first floor of his house. Without a source, though, I can't post an answer.